# Runners in her hose?

Tags: meaning

This is from a song that Johnny Cash sang. I want to know what *runners in her hose* means:

> Back when we could laugh and play
>       On family reunion day
>       Didn't we all look funny
>       In our 1950s clothes?
>       Your daddy wore that greasy stuff
>        Your brother drank more than enough
>        Your mom wore penny loafers
>        With runners in her hose

I guess *hose* is short for pantyhose but despite having many alternatives for *runner* my dictionary doesn't have any that fit into this sentence.

Comment: ... 'ladders in her stockings'? (and 'runners in her hose' - was she a firefighter?)

Comment: Pantyhose weren't introduced until the 1960s. In the 1950s, in the US, _hose_ meant stockings, in this case nylon stockings. And a woman wearing hose could have _a run_, or in some places and cases _a runner_, which means a spreading vertical rip, held together with crosswise threads.

Comment: Hose is short for hosiery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Women's hosiery of that era were not yet pantyhose, but rather thigh-high hosiery held in place by garter belts. The nylon from which the hosiery was made was subject to having a defect occur, called a run, that would leave a visible line or streak down the length of the hose. Wearing such hosiery was at least mildly embarrassing and to some extent a sign of low social or financial standing since the woman was not able to afford better (or more) hosiery. The same thing can happen with pantyhose, but that was not what the Johnny Cash song had in mind.

1. a series of unravelled stitches, esp in stockings or tights; ladder

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/run

Comment: [An image of a run](http://img.ehowcdn.com/article-new-thumbnail/ehow/images/a01/up/jf/fix-panty-hose-run-800x800.jpg)

Comment: @Superbest - ["See how they run"](http://rock.rapgenius.com/The-beatles-lady-madonna-lyrics) (verse 4, of course)